# Terraform AWS S3 Bucket Configuration Update to Resolve Deprecated Warning

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've been using Terraform to manage my AWS infrastructure, and I recently encountered a warning related to my AWS S3 bucket configuration. Here's the current Terraform code for my S3 bucket:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "testdocuments" {
  bucket_prefix = format("sd.%s.ml.test-", var.name)
  acl           = "private"

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following Terraform and AWS provider versions:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "= 0.14.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.76.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Recently, I started receiving the following warning:

```
Warning: Argument is deprecated

  on s3.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "testdocuments":
   1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "documents" {

Use the aws_s3_bucket_versioning resource instead

(and 182 more similar warnings elsewhere)

Error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field UserInfo.tags of type string
```

From the documentation, I understand that the `acl` and `server_side_encryption_configuration` properties are deprecated. I would like to update my configuration in a way that doesn't impact the existing infrastructure, which means no property changes, and no delete and recreate of the S3 bucket. What's the recommended approach to achieve this?

Comment: You need to import the resources into the state with new resource names, details are here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#s3-bucket-refactor.

Comment: Also, what is the exact provider version you have installed?

Comment: @MarkoE I am using hashicorp/aws v3.76.1
Also, the link you shared is for v4. then why I seeing these error

Comment: Actually, it seems the issue is with tags? These are deprecation warnings only. Do you have tags defined anywhere?

Comment: The error is indeed an incorrect type for the value for the `tags` parameter. However, it is very odd that the validation failed during an attempted JSON unmarshalling as opposed to during the `tfsdk` marshalling/value type checking.

Comment: @MarkoE I use tags lots of places in my terraform code? :(

Comment: @MatthewSchuchard It was working fine till last week. I haven't made any changes in the version. why all of sudden I am getting this. Any pointer on how to fix it?

Comment: @gamechanger17 well, have tags changed anywhere? If you are using a VCS, you could easily identify what has changed and where.

Comment: @MarkoE yeah. I am using git. There is no change at all in the terraform dir. All of sudden I am seeing this issue.

Comment: Ok given this new information the root cause is most likely an incompatibility between the current AWS API and the AWS Go SDK used by this old version of the provider. Since you cannot use an older version of the AWS API you would essentially be forced to update the provider version to one that is compatible with the AWS API.